# Action Chains fail in Safari browser

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, macos-mojave

I`m trying to create move to element action using ActionChains in Safari 12.0 browser, but get the next error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Encountered key input source with invalid 'value' in payload: {
actions =     (
            {
        duration = 0;
        type = pause;
    }
);
id = key;
type = key;
}
```

The same test is passed success in any browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Ie, Edge etc) but fails in Safari.

Source code, which create this actions:

```
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/header/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div[1]/span[1]')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
```

Comment: Can you include the code you use to create the action?

Comment: @skandigraun, sure. I have update question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Unfortunately Safari [does not support](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4136) this WebDriver action :(

Comment: See the workaround mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53633796/2261442

Answer (score 0):

Commenting the line `#self.w3c_actions.key_action.pause()` from class `ActionChains` solved problem for me
But its a workaround and needs proper fix from driver